# OS Install Using IPMI Tool

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I am working on a script which would allow me to reload the OS on my machine without having to use the IPMI, attach media, hit the DEL key, boot to media, etc. I know once I get media attached using IPMI, I can use IPMITool and run the following command to boot to the media

```
ipmitool -I lan -H IPADDRESS  -U USERNAME -P 'PASSWORD' chassis bootdev cdrom
```

However, my question is how can I use ipmitool or any code to have a script attach the media. From my understanding, it does not seem to be posible using ipmitool. Is there any other way to get a script to attach the media (ex: CentOS 5.7 netinstall media)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd just use PXE, it's what it's designed to do.

Comment: Besides PXE is there any other way?

Comment: I'm sure there are, but PXE's the way I'd go.

Comment: If the server has HP iLO2 or advanced management from a different vendor, it might possible to initialize cdrom redirection from the commandline connecting to the management processor. Which platform do you have?